# How do I choose which indent format to use for same file type?

Tags: indentation

I have multiple indent rules for same file type. I'd like to try them separately. How do I see which one is active? :set filetype is correct.

I did manage to change the rules by disabling all other indent files manually, but there probably is a better way?

In this case I have >5 different Javascript indent versions I'd like to test. (Mac default, Pangloss, web-indent, etc.)

Comment: Can you provide an example of one or more of your indent rules? It's not clear what you are sking.

Comment: Better? Rule being a indent file that (to my understanding) does the formatting when you indent lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most indent files will either:

- set `indentexpr` and `indentkeys`;
- set `cindent` and `cinoptions`.

You can check the values by appending a question mark, and you can see where an option was set by prefixing it with `:verbose`. For example for JS:

```
:verbose set cindent?
  cindent
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/javascript.vim
:verbose set indentexpr?
  indentexpr=
```

Or for Python:

```
:verbose set cindent? 
  nocindent
:verbose set indent
  indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/python.vim
```

Comment: :verbose answered my question!